# Can I haz espresso? Proposal for improving the review tab

Tags: feature-request, review

When reviewing tag wiki excerpts, I always find myself wondering which tag I'm reviewing. This is because the "tag wiki excerpt" is bigger and better than the tag.

[image: Espresso]

I propose to make two changes to this page.

```
1. Put the tag *after* the text "tag wiki excerpt:"
2. Make the tag bigger than the text.
```

Comment: I hope you rejected that edit; we very specifically ask people *not* to [regurgitate Wikipedia](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102314/141911) or [post generic definitions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117017/141911).

Comment: @Aaronut, I'm sorry to say I wasn't aware of those and I approved the edit.

Comment: Good point. If the devs have the time to work on this, they could add a canned instruction "Please don't approve tag wikis which contain nothing but a definition of the tag". We have many well meaning users who suggest such wikis and others who approve them because they are not aware of the policy.